# What is this Style script with porn links on bottom of my website?

Tags: hyperlink, styles, spam

Hi I have a site built with latest ruby on rails 7.0.4 and ruby 3.2.0 with some https://www.getpapercss.com/ and cloudflair and digitalocean component library and this morning I see in bottom of site source this line:
[image]

```
 <style>a[href^="http://intent.bingads.com/"],a[href^="https://thaudray.com/"],a[href^="https://aj1070.online/"],[data-m-ad-id],a[href^="https://awecrptjmp.com/"],a[href^="https://www.iyalc.com/"],a[data-url^="http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"],a[href^="https://go.nordvpn.net/aff"] > img,a[href^="https://deliver.tf2www.com/"],a[href^="https://join.virtualtaboo.com/track/"],a[href^="https://track.totalav.com/"],a[href^="https://www.sweetdeals.com"],a[href^="https://ads.planetwin365affiliate.com/redirect.aspx?"],a[href^="http://enter.anabolic.com/track/"],a[href^="https://camfapr.com/landing/click/"],a[data-redirect^="http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"],a[href^="https://a-ads.com/"],div[id^="dfp-ad-"],a[href="//rufflycouncil.com/"],app-advertisement,a[data-widget-outbrain-redirect^="http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"],a[href^="http://affiliates.thrixxx.com/"],div[data-role="sidebarAd"],a[href^="http://https://www.get-express-vpn.com/offer/"],a[href^="https://ismlks.com/"],a[href^="https://axdsz.pro/"],div[id^="div-ads-"],a[href^="https://cagothie.net/"],a[href^="https://uncensored.game/"],[href^="https://go.astutelinks.com/"],a[href^="https://trf.bannerator.com/"],[href^="https://cpa.10kfreesilver.com/"],a[href^="https://claring-loccelkin.com/"],[href^="https://go.4rabettraff.com/"],a[href^="http://www.adultdvdempire.com/?partner_id="][href*="&utm_"],a[href^="https://syndication.optimizesrv.com/"],a[href^="https://syndication.dynsrvtbg.com/"],app-ad,a[href^="//agacelebir.com/"],[data-adblockkey],a[href^="https://go.goasrv.com/"],div[data-native_ad],a[href^="http://cam4com.go2cloud.org/aff_c?"],[href^="http://join.michelle-austin.com/"],a[href^="https://prf.hn/click/"][href*="/creativeref:"] > img,a[href^="https://www.adsexse.com/x/"],div[data-dfp-id],a[href^="https://bs.serving-sys.com"],div[id^="adfox_"],a[href^="https://tour.mrskin.com/"],[href^="https://noqreport.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://frameworkdeserve.com/"],div[id^="taboola-stream-"],[href="https://ourgoldguy.com/contact/"] img,a[href^="https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/"] > img,div[id^="advads_"],[class^="div-gpt-ad"],a[href^="https://a.montangop.top/"],a[href^="https://black77854.com/"],a[href^="https://track.adform.net/"],[href^="https://antiagingbed.com/discount/"] > img,[href^="https://clk.right-wing-health.com/"],a[href^="https://www.sheetmusicplus.com/?aff_id="],a[href^="//apptjmp.com/"],a[href^="https://misspkl.com/"],a[href^="https://transfer.xe.com/signup/track/redirect?"],[data-ez-name],a[href^="https://takeallsoft.ru/"],div[id^="ad_rect_"],[data-name="adaptiveConstructorAd"],div[id^="advads-"],[href^="https://mystore.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://www.goldenfrog.com/vyprvpn?offer_id="][href*="&aff_id="],a[href^="https://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/"],a[href^="https://static.fleshlight.com/images/banners/"],a[href^="https://join.sexworld3d.com/track/"],a[href^="http://go.fpmarkets.com/"],a[href^="https://partners.fxoro.com/click.php?"],a[href^="https://go.goaserv.com/"],a[href^="https://pongidsrunback.com/"],div[data-insertion],a[href^="https://adnetwrk.com/"],a[href^="https://affiliate.rusvpn.com/click.php?"],a[href^="https://engine.trackingdesks.com/"],[href^="https://go.affiliatexe.com/"],[data-advadstrackid],a[href^="https://track.afcpatrk.com/"],a[href^="https://go.cmtaffiliates.com/"],[href^="http://www.mypillow.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://bongacams10.com/track?"],a[href^="https://clickadilla.com/"],a[href^="https://albionsoftwares.com/"],AD-TRIPLE-BOX,a[href^="https://www.sugarinstant.com/?partner_id="],a[href^="https://refpazkjixes.top/"],a[href^="https://gohere.pl/"],a[href^="https://chaturbate.com/in/?tour="],a[href^="https://ads-for-free.com/click.php?"],a[href^="http://www.adultempire.com/unlimited/promo?"][href*="&partner_id="],[id^="chp_ads_block"],a[data-redirect^="https://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"],[href^="https://mylead.global/stl/"] > img,a[href^="http://www.mrskin.com/tour"],a[href^="https://nutrientassumptionclaims.com/"],div[id^="ads300_100-widget-"],ADS-RIGHT,[href^="https://cipledecline.buzz/"],a[href^="https://msecure117.com/"],a[href^="https://ads.cdn.live/"],a[href^="//lambingsyddir.com/"],a[href^="https://webroutetrk.com/"],a[href^="https://t.adating.link/"],a[href^="https://lobimax.com/"],a[href^="https://land.brazzersnetwork.com/landing/"],a[href^="https://awptjmp.com/"],a[href^="https://go.strpjmp.com/"],a[href^="https://www.purevpn.com/"][href*="&utm_source=aff-"],a[href^="https://a.bestcontentoperation.top/"],[data-ad-manager-id],a[href^="https://www.camsoda.com/enter.php?id="],AMP-AD,div[id^="adspot-"],a[href^="http://d2.zedo.com/"],a[href^="http://www.gfrevenge.com/landing/"],topadblock,[data-revive-zoneid],a[href^="https://chaturbate.jjgirls.com/?track="],[href^="https://www.reimageplus.com/"],a[href^="https://odnxe.lncredlbiedate.com/"],a[href^="https://click.dtiserv2.com/"],[href^="https://join.playboyplus.com/track/"],a[href^="http://bc.vc/?r="],a[href^="https://track.interactivegf.com/"],a[href^="https://www.infowarsstore.com/"] > img,[data-dynamic-ads],a[onmousedown^="this.href='https://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"][target="_blank"] + .ob_source,AD-SLOT,amp-ad-custom,div[id^="gtm-ad-"],[data-d-ad-id],a[data-obtrack^="http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"],[href^="http://www.fleshlightgirls.com/"],a[href^="https://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"],a[href^="https://s.zlink2.com/"],[href^="https://ilovemyfreedoms.com/landing-"],a[href^="https://ovb.im/"],a[href^="http://affiliate.glbtracker.com/"],a[href^="https://mediaserver.gvcaffiliates.com/renderBanner.do?"],iframe[src^="http://www.adpeepshosted.com/"],div[data-mpu1],a[href^="https://pl.premium4kflix.website/"],a[href^="https://speedsupermarketdonut.com/"],a[href*="http://MyPillow.com"] > img,[href^="https://zstacklife.com/"] img,iframe[src^="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/"],a[href^="https://www.awin1.com/cread.php?awinaffid="],a[href^="https://prf.hn/click/"][href*="/adref:"] > img,a[href^="https://incisivetrk.cvtr.io/click?"],a[href^="https://www.healthrangerstore.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://www.kingsoffetish.com/tour?partner_id="],a[href^="https://mmwebhandler.aff-online.com/"],a[href^="https://trusted-click-host.com/"],[href^="https://mypatriotsupply.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://track.clickmoi.xyz/"],a[href^="https://traffdaq.com/"],a[href^="http://adultgames.xxx/"],a[href^="https://lnkxt.bannerator.com/"],a[href^="https://someperceptionparade.com/"],guj-ad,a[href^="https://offers.refchamp.com/"],[href^="https://www.restoro.com/"],a[href^="https://go.hpyrdr.com/"],a[href^="https://landing.brazzersnetwork.com/"],a[href^="https://bngpt.com/"],a[href^="https://tracking.gitads.io/"],a[href^="https://reinstandpointdumbest.com/"],div[id^="gpt_ad_"],[href^="https://track.fiverr.com/visit/"] > img,[href^="https://routewebtk.com/"],a[href^="https://deliver.ptgncdn.com/"],a[href^="https://syndication.exoclick.com/"],a[href^="https://dfsdkkka.com/"],[href^="https://go.xlrdr.com"],div[id^="ad-server-"],a[href^="http://go.xtbaffiliates.com/"],div[id^="ad-inserter-"],a[href^="https://track.themadtrcker.com/"],[class^="s2nPlayer"],a[href^="https://mediaserver.entainpartners.com/renderBanner.do?"],a[href^="https://oackoubs.com/"],a[href^="https://m.do.co/c/"] > img,a[href^="http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"],[href^="http://go.cm-trk2.com/"],a[href^="https://go.247traffic.com/"],a[href^="https://go.tmrjmp.com"],[id^="ad-wrap-"],a[data-oburl^="https://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"],[href="https://www.masstortfinancing.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://s.zlink1.com/"],a[href^="https://www.adultempire.com/"][href*="?partner_id="],a[href^="https://1free33style.com/"],a[href^="https://movie.download-file.org/"],a[href^="https://pcm.bannerator.com/"],a[href^="https://dooloust.net/"],a[href^="https://trappist-1d.com/"],a[href^="//chrif8kdstie.com/"],a[href^="https://natour.naughtyamerica.com/track/"],[href^="https://www.mypatriotsupply.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://pb-track.com/"],a[href^="https://track.bruceads.com/"],amp-fx-flying-carpet,a[href^="https://www.clicktraceclick.com/"],a[href^="https://reachtrgt.com/"],a[href^="https://www.sheetmusicplus.com/"][href*="?aff_id="],a[href^="//syndication.dynsrvtbg.com/"],a[href^="https://porngames.adult/?SID="],a[href^="http://allaptair.club/"],div.fadeInDown[id$="____equal"][class$="____equal"],[href^="https://engine.gettopple.com/"],a[href^="https://adjoincomprise.com/"],a[href^="https://www.profitablecpmgate.com/"],a[href^="//go.eabids.com/"],div[id^="ads250_250-widget-"],a[href^="https://www.jackery.com?aff="] > img,[href^="https://glersakr.com/"],a[href^="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/"],a[href^="https://clicks.pipaffiliates.com/"],div[id^="ad_position_"],a[href^="https://affcpatrk.com/"],a[href^="https://as.sexad.net/"],div[id^="_vdo_ads_player_ai_"],a[href^="https://moneynow.one/"],a[href^="https://refpa4903566.top/"],a[href^="https://playuhd.host/"],a[href^="https://go.xlviiirdr.com"],a[href^="https://meet-to-fuck.com/"],[href^="http://homemoviestube.com/"],a[href^="https://go.xlviirdr.com"],[href^="https://kingered-banctours.com/"],a[href^="https://bestcond1tions.com/"],a[href^="https://fastestvpn.com/lifetime-special-deal?a_aid="],a[href^="https://go.xlvirdr.com"],a[href^="https://go.trackitalltheway.com/"],div[data-id-advertdfpconf],a[href^="https://go.xxxiijmp.com"],[class^="amp-ad-"],[onclick^="location.href='http://www.reimageplus.com"],a[href^="https://streamate.com/landing/click/"],[href^="https://zone.gotrackier.com/"],[href^="https://infinitytrk.com/"],a[href^="https://iqbroker.com/"][href*="?aff="],a[href^="https://go.julrdr.com/"],a[href^="https://adsrv4k.com/"],a[href^="http://www.onclickmega.com/jump/next.php?"],a[href^="https://clixtrac.com/"],a[href*=".zlinkm.com/"],[href^="http://join.shemale.xxx/"],a-ad,a[href^="https://www.brazzersnetwork.com/landing/"],a[href^="https://aff-ads.stickywilds.com/"],[data-css-class="dfp-inarticle"],iframe[src^="http://ad.yieldmanager.com/"],[data-mobile-ad-id],a[href^="https://tracking.trackcasino.co/"],div[id*="ScriptRoot"],a[href^="https://waisheph.com/"],[href^="https://shrugartisticelder.com"],[data-role="tile-ads-module"],a[href^="https://chaturbate.com/in/?track="],div[data-ad-placeholder],a[href^="https://track.healthtrader.com/"],a[href^="https://medleyads.com/"],div[data-adzone],a[href^="http://www.coiwqe.site/"],div[id^="zergnet-widget"],img[src^="https://images.purevpnaffiliates.com"],[href^="https://www.brighteonstore.com/products/"] img,a[href*="//lkstrck2.com/"],a[href^="https://www.arthrozene.com/"][href*="?tid="],[href^="https://join.girlsoutwest.com/"],a[href^="https://thechleads.pro/"],[href^="https://www.hostg.xyz/"] > img,a[href^="https://twinrdsyn.com/"],a[href^="https://iactrivago.ampxdirect.com/"],[href^="http://clicks.totemcash.com/"],a[href^="https://tracking.comfortclick.eu/"],[href^="https://join3.bannedsextapes.com"],a[href*=".trust.zone"],a[href^="https://www.highperformancecpmgate.com/"],a[href^="https://queersodadults.com/"],[href^="https://click2cvs.com/"],[data-ad-module],a[href^="https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/"],[href^="https://rapidgator.net/article/premium/ref/"],a[href^="https://tupitea.co/"],a[href^="https://wittered-mainging.com/"],a[href^="https://delivery.porn.com/"],a[href^="//wagerprocuratorantiterrorist.com/"],a[href^="https://k2s.cc/pr/"],[href^="https://www.mypillow.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://dianches-inchor.com/"],a[href^="https://iac.ampxdirect.com/"],a[href^="https://serve.awmdelivery.com/"],div[class^="Adstyled__AdWrapper-"],[href^="http://www.pingperfect.com/aff.php"],[href^="http://globsads.com/"],a[href^="https://a.bestcontentfood.top/"],div[class^="kiwi-ad-wrapper"],div[data-native-ad],a[href^="https://www.rabbits.webcam/?id="],div[data-adunit],a[href^="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click"],a[href^="https://bestdatinghere.life/"],[id^="google_ads_iframe"],a[href^="http://tc.tradetracker.net/"] > img,a[href^="https://financeads.net/tc.php?"],div[id^="ads300_250-widget-"],bottomadblock,[href^="https://www.cloudways.com/en/?id"],a[href^="https://avtub.click/assets/link.php"],div[class^="gpt-ad-hor"],a[href^="https://landing1.brazzersnetwork.com"],a[href^="https://vlnk.me/"],a[href^="https://bluedelivery.pro/"],a[href^="https://www.vfreecams.com/in/?track="],div[jsdata*="CarouselPLA-"][data-id^="CarouselPLA-"],a[onmousedown^="this.href='http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"][target="_blank"],a[onmousedown^="this.href='https://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"][target="_blank"],a[href^="https://tm-offers.gamingadult.com/"],[href^="https://shiftnetwork.infusionsoft.com/go/"] > img,[href^="https://v.investologic.co.uk/"],a[href^="http://partners.etoro.com/"],a[href^="https://www.oboom.com/ref/"],div[data-alias="300x250 Ad 1"],article.ad,a[href^="http://wct.link/"],a[data-url^="http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"] + .author,div[data-ad-wrapper],[href^="https://totlnkcl.com/"],[href^="http://join.shemalesfromhell.com/"],a[href^="https://earandmarketing.com/"],div[id^="vuukle-ad-"],span[id^="ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-"],a[href^="https://ads.leovegas.com/redirect.aspx?"],a[href^="https://prf.hn/click/"][href*="/camref:"] > img,a[href^="https://meet-sexhere.com/"],[class^="chp_ads_block"],[href^="https://www.targetingpartner.com/"],a[href^="https://aaucwbe.com/"],a[href^="https://taghaugh.com/"],div[data-alias="300x250 Ad 2"],a[href^="https://click.hoolig.app/"],div[id^="ezoic-pub-ad-"],a[href^="https://www.get-express-vpn.com/offer/"],a[href^="https://fakelay.com/"],a[href^="https://ad.zanox.com/ppc/"] > img,a[href^="https://www.bet365.com/"][href*="affiliate="],a[href^="https://uncensored3d.com/"],a[href^="https://www.financeads.net/tc.php?"],div[data-adunit-path],a[href^="https://join.virtuallust3d.com/"],a[href^="https://maymooth-stopic.com/"],a[href^="https://www.bang.com/?aff="],a[href^="https://a.bestcontentweb.top/"],a[href^="https://dialling-abutory.com/"],a[href^="https://americafirstpolls.com/"],[href^="https://www.avantlink.com/click.php"] img,a[href^="http://rs-stripe.wsj.com/stripe/redirect"],display-ad-component,a[href^="https://www.chngtrack.com/"],a[href*=".engine.adglare.net/"],a[href^="https://get.surfshark.net/aff_c?"][href*="&aff_id="] > img,div[id^="google_dfp_"],a[href^="http://ad.doubleclick.net/"],a[href^="https://loboclick.com"],div[id^="gpt-ad-hor"],div[id^="ad-div-"],a[href^="https://fast-redirecting.com/"],a[href^="https://t.aslnk.link/"],a[href^="https://fertilitycommand.com/"],[href^="https://istlnkcl.com/"],a[href^="https://www.liquidfire.mobi/"],[href^="http://join.hardcoreshemalevideo.com/"],a[href^="http://adf.ly/?id="],a[href^="//coarsewary.com/"],div[id^="lazyad-"],a[href^="https://go.xtbaffiliates.com/"],a[href^="http://www.advcashpro.com/aff/"],a[onmousedown^="this.href='http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"][target="_blank"] + .ob_source,a[href^="https://dishphysics.com/"],div[id^="adrotate_widgets-"],a[href^="https://go.skinstrip.net"][href*="?campaignId="],a[href^="https://go.xxxjmp.com"],[href^="http://trafficare.net/"],a[href^="https://see.kmisln.com/"],[href^="https://awbbjmp.com/"],div[id^="crt-"][style],a[href^="https://engine.phn.doublepimp.com/"],zeus-ad,a[href^="https://my-movie.club/"],a[href^="https://promo-bc.com/"],a[href^="https://burpee.xyz/"],div[id^="js-dfp-"],a[href^="http://adultfriendfinder.com/go/page/landing"],a[data-oburl^="http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"],DFP-AD,div[class^="Display_displayAd"],div[aria-label="Ads"],a[href^="https://go.xxxijmp.com"],a[href^="https://go.currency.com/"],a[href^="https://traffic.bannerator.com/"],a[href^="https://gghf.mobi/"],a[href^="http://adserver.adreactor.com/"],a[href^="https://losingoldfry.com/"],a[href^="https://funkydaters.com/"],[href^="http://misslinkvocation.com/"],a[href*="https://www.sweetdeals.com/"] img,a[href^="https://www.mrskin.com/tour"],a[href^="https://go.dmzjmp.com"],div[id^="yandex_ad"],[href^="https://wct.link/"],a[href^="http://www.FriendlyDuck.com/"],a[href^="https://mk-cdn.net/"],a[href^="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click"],a[href^="https://as.conjectwatson.com/"],a[href^="http://hotcandyland.com/partner/"],[href="https://masstortfinancing.com"] img,a[href^="https://www.mrskin.com/account/"],a[target="_blank"][onmousedown="this.href^='http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"],a[data-redirect^="this.href='http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"],a[href^="https://myusenet.xyz/"],[href^="http://residenceseeingstanding.com/"],a[href^="https://ads.betfair.com/redirect.aspx?"],a[href^="https://billing.purevpn.com/aff.php"] > img,a[href^="https://landing.brazzersplus.com/"],a[href^="https://geniusdexchange.com/"],[href^="http://mypillow.com/"] > img,div[id*="MarketGid"],a[href^="//benoopto.com/"],[href^="http://join.trannies-fuck.com/"],div[id^="dfp-slot-"],a[href^="https://agacelebir.com/"],[href^="https://r.kraken.com/"],a[href^="https://watchmygirlfriend.tv/"],a[href^="https://engine.blueistheneworanges.com/"],a[href^="https://ptapjmp.com/"],a[href^="https://porntubemate.com/"],a[href^="http://ads2.williamhill.com/redirect.aspx?"],a[href^="https://get2nesoft1.ru/"],a[href^="https://ad.atdmt.com/"],a[href^="https://go.zybrdr.com"],a[href^="https://mob1ledev1ces.com/"],a[href^="https://go.etoro.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://cpartner.bdswiss.com/"],div[id^="ad_script_"],a[href^="https://go.xlivrdr.com"],[onclick*="content.ad/"],a[href^="//voyeurhit.com/cs/"],[href^="https://www.herbanomic.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://topoffers.com/"][href*="/?pid="],[id^="ad_sky"],hl-adsense,div[id^="ad-gpt-"],a[href^="https://torguard.net/aff.php"] > img,div[id^="rc-widget-"],div[id^="ad_bnr_"],a[href^="http://betahit.click/"],a[href^="https://bongacams2.com/track?"],a[href^="http://secure.vivid.com/track/"],div[data-ad-targeting],a[href^="https://t.hrtyj.com/"],a[href^="https://ausoafab.net/"],a[href^="https://5hjdbfjfd5.monster/"],a[href^="https://go.alxbgo.com/"],[data-freestar-ad],a[href^="https://ad.kubiccomps.icu/"],a[href^="https://lead1.pl/"],[id^="div-gpt-ad"],[href^="https://affect3dnetwork.com/track/"],ad-desktop-sidebar,a[href^="https://track.ultravpn.com/"],a[href^="http://m.hsrve.com/"],a[href*=".zlink9.com/"],app-large-ad,a[href*=".flndmyiove.net/"],a[href^="https://explore.findanswersnow.net/"],a[href^="http://traffic.tc-clicks.com/"],a[href^="https://cam4com.go2cloud.org/"],amp-embed[type="taboola"],[href^="https://goldforyourfuture.com/clk.trk"] img,a[href^="https://go.hpyjmp.com"],[href^="https://traffserve.com/"],a[href^="http://trk.mdrtrck.com/"],a[href^="https://trk.moviesflix4k.xyz/"],[href^="https://mypillow.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://track.afftck.com/"],a[href^="http://adtrack1.club/"],a[href^="//thaudray.com/"],a[href^="https://www.onlineusershielder.com/torrent-guard/?"],[data-template-type="nativead"],a[href^="https://wantopticalfreelance.com/"],a[href^="https://ndt5.net/"],[data-desktop-ad-id],a[href^="https://look.utndln.com/"],aside[id^="adrotate_widgets-"],a[href^="https://www.adskeeper.com"],a[href^="https://tracking.avapartner.com/"],a[href^="https://www.highperformancegate.com/"],ad-shield-ads,a[href^="https://azpresearch.club/"],[href^="https://secure.bmtmicro.com/servlets/"],a[href^="https://www.nudeidols.com/cams/"],a[href^="http://deloplen.com/"],[name^="google_ads_iframe"],a[href^="https://track.wg-aff.com"],[href^="https://affiliate.fastcomet.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://trk.watchlivesports4k.club/"],display-ads,[data-ad-width],a[href^="https://adswick.com/"],div[data-contentexchange-widget],a[href^="https://click.a-ads.com/"],[href^="https://optimizedelite.com/"] > img,[href^="http://join.rodneymoore.com/"],a[href^="https://go.markets.com/visit/?bta="],div[data-google-query-id],a[href^="https://ttf.trmobc.com/"],a[href^="https://tc.tradetracker.net/"] > img,div[id^="adngin-"],a[href^="https://www.oneclickroot.com/?tap_a="] > img,a[href^="https://ak.hetaruwg.com/"],a[href^="https://galaxyroms.net/?scr="],[href^="http://join.ts-dominopresley.com/"],a[href^="//pubads.g.doubleclick.net/"],[href^="https://freecourseweb.com/"] > .sitefriend,[href^="https://www.mystore.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://ad.doubleclick.net/"],a[href^="https://cpmspace.com/"],a[href^="https://track.effiliation.com/servlet/effi.click?"] > img,a[href^="http://www.onwebcam.com/random?t_link="],a[href^="https://go.admjmp.com/"],a[href^="https://awentw.com/"],a[href^="https://www.bebi.com"],div[data-spotim-slot],iframe[id^="google_ads_frame"],a[href^="https://go.xlirdr.com"],div[data-adname],div[id^="sticky_ad_"],a[href^="https://adultfriendfinder.com/go/page/landing"],div[class^="s-dfp-"],a[href^="https://www.mypornstarcams.com/landing/click/"],[href^="https://turtlebids.irauctions.com/"] img,a[href^="https://join.dreamsexworld.com/"],a[href^="https://a2.adform.net/"],a[href^="https://leg.xyz/?track="],a[href^="https://juicyads.in/"],[data-ad-cls],div[id^="div-gpt-"],a[href^="https://a.adtng.com/"],a[href^="http://go.247traffic.com/"],a[href^="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?"],a[href^="https://www.nutaku.net/signup/landing/"],a[href^="http://pityhostngco2.xyz/"],a[href^="https://go.cmrdr.com/"],a[href^="https://torrentsafeguard.com/?aid="],gpt-ad,div[id^="ad-position-"],[href^="//ngeoziadiyc4hi2e.com/"],a[href^="https://creacdn.top-convert.com/"],[id^="section-ad-banner"],a[href^="https://spygasm.com/track?"],aside[id^="advads_ad_widget-"],a[href^="http://bongacams.com/track?"],a[href^="https://fleshlight.sjv.io/"],a[href^="https://ads.ad4game.com/"],a[href^="https://meet-sex-here.com/"],div[class^="native-ad-"],a[href^="https://itubego.com/video-downloader/?affid="],amp-connatix-player,a[href^="https://t.hrtye.com/"],[href^="https://detachedbates.com/"],ark-top-ad,[href^="https://ad.admitad.com/"],a[href^="https://1startfiledownload1.com/"],a[href^="https://a.medfoodhome.com/"],a[href^="https://cams.imagetwist.com/in/?track="],a[href^="https://scurewall.co/"],a[href^="https://vo2.qrlsx.com/"],a[href^="https://affpa.top/"],a[href^="https://t.mobtya.com/"],div[data-content="Advertisement"],[href^="https://goldcometals.com/clk.trk"],a[href^="https://go.ebrokerserve.com/"],a[href^="http://static.fleshlight.com/images/banners/"],[href^="http://join.shemalepornstar.com/"],[id^="ad_slider"],a[href^="https://tragency-clesburg.icu/"],a[href^="https://banners.livepartners.com/"],[href="https://jdrucker.com/gold"] > img,a[href^="http://tour.mrskin.com/"],a[href^="https://datingbests.life/"],a[href^="https://aweptjmp.com/"],a[href^="https://intenseaffiliates.com/redirect/"],a[href^="https://adserver.adreactor.com/"],a[href^="http://click.payserve.com/"],a[href^="http://bodelen.com/"],a[href^="//go.xlviiirdr.com"],[href^="https://trackfin.asia/"],[href^="https://stvkr.com/"],a[href^="https://t.grtyi.com/"],a[href^="https://go.gldrdr.com/"],a[href^="https://www.passeura.com/"] { display: none !important }</style></body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was happening to me too (Mac/Chrome). After some research, this is related to the "Threat Protection" feature of NordVPN. If you turn Threat Protection off, the injected code will disappear. Their reasoning is that this hides links and ads from sites Nord has deemed infected or dangerous. Another poster says this is to add links and then hide them, but I have not been able to find any evidence of links being added, just the style injection.

If you don't want that functionality, you can turn off the Threat Protection. You can find more info about the feature here: https://nordvpn.com/features/threat-protection/

Comment: Just tested, it looks like you said if you switch off it disappears. I was contacted from NordVPN some head of security and he mentioned the same like you can turn off, but however, I think its not so good solution for protections, to append some html additionally to every page you open. I am for protection but implementation is not so good. They said they will fix it soon. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

At the end it happens that NordVPN Win 11 desktop app doing this. If you use VPN on every site they will add like 500 links for advertising and hide them with some CSS. Many of these links are porn sites/ domains.
This is not okay at all. Definitely paid service should not manipulate with our browser content. This is privacy and security issue.
Here is my blog about with [video](https://blog.rubyonrails.ba/articles/paid-vpn-s-spamming-us-all-the-time-is-this-okay).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It's not on that particular website, it's on your computer. Check the source code of other websites and you'll find the same thing there too.

There's very little information and I have yet to find a way to remove it. No antivirus or malware detection software of mine can detect it.

Hard-resetting my entire computer later for the 2nd time this week, as I managed to get it back within hours of doing that very same thing yesterday.

My current theory is that it's included with an Excel add-on I use called KuTools, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hey I found what was the problem in my case its about NordVPN. They do that I am using Win 11 desktop app and if you turn of VPN style doesnt exist if you turn on it will be visible. I have contacted them support NordVPN and first they say its a bug and later its the feature. Not sure is this allowed at all. They as service should't append anything to our browser, porn links especially!  I am writing a blog about and I will soon add it here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing and yes it turned out to be NordVPN Threat Protection. However if you go into settings you should find a "Use Lite version" of Threat Protection. This will give you some of the benefits but will not append all those links into your browser.

Settings from the Windows NordVPN app

[image: NordVPN Threat Protection settings on Windows]

Settings from the Mac NordVPN app

[image: NordVPN Threat Protection settings on Mac]

Comment: it looks like they adding those options all the time. I am sure I have never seen that button '...lite  before.

Answer (score 1):

I recently saw this as well, but I HAD to disable the Threat Protection Lite button, because if it is enabled while I ALSO have the main NordVPN app running on my desktop, it causes site certificate errors for trusted sites such as DELL's SecureWorks...so for browser session digital artifacts, we just have to keep in mind that the code at the end may very well be code added by NordVPN.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a built-in adblock extention in Opera GX. Ironically the extention it's called "Privacy protection".